# Restrict access to some categories for not logged in customers

Tags: magento2, catalog, menu, category-listing

What's the best approach for restricting access to some categories and products in those categories on front-end for not logged in customers.

we need to hide category from the menu and catalog search, and if customer tries to access category page directly with link, or some product (in category)  page, we display some default message (To view the products you need to log in.)

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new category attribute (yes/no flag) called `restricted` or something like that. Here are the docs to help you with that: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/howto/add_category_attribute.html

Then you can create an around plugin for the method `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View::execute`. This is the controller action that handles the category view. here are the docs for that: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Your plugin class can look something like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Pugin\Controller\Category;

class ViewPlugin
{
    private $storeManager;
    private $categoryRepository;
    private $customerSession;
    private $request;
    private $redirectFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory
    ) {
         $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
         $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
         $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
         $this->request = $request;
         $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        try {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->request->getParam('id'), $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $category->getData('restricted')) {
                $result = $this->redirectFactory->create();
                $result->setPath('customer/account/login');
                return $result;
            }
            return $proceed();
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return $proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is not tested so watch out for typos.

Comment: Hi Maruis, Thank you for your reply. I edited my question, we need to hide category from all the front-end. you reply I think it will hide category only from category view ?

Comment: In this case it gets way more complicated. You will need to hook into the main menu mechanism `Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu` and excldue the categories that are restricted. Maybe override the method `getCategoryTree` and add an extra filter in case the user is not logged in `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('restricted' => ['neq' => 1])` or something like that. And then you need to hook into every product collection and exclude products that might be related to the restricted categories. I don't know exactly how you can do that, sorry.